# Laravel - Return only multiple relationships with records from controller or model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm returing a model with all the related models.
My problem is that perhaps some models don't have records so they are returned in my `$property` variable as empty and I have to evaluate their existence in blade (not done yet)
Is there any way in controller or parent model to return only the child relationships which have records? Or any blade directive to evaluate these cases?
All relationships are 1:M.

Regards!

**Controller Code**

```
class PropertyController extends Controller
{
    public function details($id)
    {
        $property = Property::with('attributes', 'addons', 'distributions', 'images', 'attributes_2', 'services')
                    ->where('prop_id', $id)
                    ->first();
        // dd($property);
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.propertymodal', compact('property'));
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for `whereHas()` method? I think you want to check relationship data existence

Answer (score 0):

Sir u have the same result with this code?? (just trying to help, im new in this world)

```
return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.propertymodal', compact(array('property')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PropertyController extends Controller
{
    public function details($id)
    {
        $relations = ['attributes', 'addons', 'distributions', 'images', 'attributes_2', 'services']
        $property = Property::with($relations)->whereHas($relations)
                    ->where('prop_id', $id)
                    ->first();
        // dd($property);
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.propertymodal', compact('property'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That approach is not working for me, I believe```whereHas``` needs a closure.
This is the errorr recieved:

```Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I changed code as follows and recieved the expected result:

```
public function details($id)
    {
        $property = Property::with(['attributes' => function ($builder) {
            $builder->where('pa_value', '!=', '');
        }])
            ->with('addons', 'distributions', 'images', 'attributes_2', 'services')
            ->where('prop_id', $id)
            ->withCount('attributes', 'addons', 'distributions', 'images', 'attributes_2', 'services')
            ->first();
        dd($property);
        return view('pages.processes.offerdemand.matchs.propertymodal', compact('property'));
    }
```